# Set format to text when export by php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'CardNumber')


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . $i, $objResult["CardNumber"]);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i need to set format column in excel when i export to php

Comment: i need to set format column on excel when i export data to excel
my problem it's when i export data card number form data base is 4284710000008725 but it show in excel is 4284710000008720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#number-formats), to set a format to TEXT, you'd use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

**EDIT**

However, it transpires that what you want to do isn't to set a style format to `TEXT`, but to store a long numeric value as a string

For this purpose, PHPExcel has the `setCellValueExplicit()` method:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit('A' . $i, $objResult["CardNumber"]);
```

which defaults to setting the value as datatype string rather than identifying that it is a numeric and setting it to datatype number

Comment: thank for reply sir but code is not work
thep proble it's when export from data base to excel 
cardnumber is 4284710000008725 but it show on excel 4284710000008720 
so i need to set column to be text format  then set values into it sir

Comment: thank you sir is effect when i user setCellValueExplicit() and set values type